# Ajax to flask is sending an empty object

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to send an array from my javascript client to my flask server.  I can log the array right before the ajax post-call and see that it exists and looks right. However, when I print it on the flask server-side I receive an empty string.

I have tried 2 different versions of javascript to post it:

Here is the first

```
$.post("/javamongo", {
                    data: JSON.stringify(data)
                }, function(err, req, resp){
                    window.locationhref = "/results/"+resp["responseJSON"]["uuid"];
                })
```

here is the second

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/javamongo',
    type: "POST",
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    data: {'data': data}
    }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
```

Both are producing different versions of empty when they are received.  On my flask server I have tried:

```
data = request.data
```

and
`data = request.data.decode("utf-8")`

as well as passing those through JSON.loads() all to no avail.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not a Flask dev...are you expecting json body being sent? If so you misspelled contentType and would need to stringify the whole data object. Otherwise the $.post version would send as form encoded data the same as submitting an html form with `action="post"`

Comment: First, inspect the request in the browser's dev tools and make sure it's sent correctly. Next, try to log everything on the flask side. Start with `request`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `request.form['data']` instead, since the method you are using is `post`